# How to use Nest and mutate to create a model from training set and then apply it on a test data in R (tidymodels)

Tags: r, tidymodels

```
library(tidymodels)

Train %>% nest(-Groups) %>% 
        mutate(fit=map(data,~lm(X~Y+Z,x=.)),
               augmented = map(fit,augment),
               predict = map2(fit,Y,Z)) %>%
        unnest(augmented) %>% select(-data)
```

This works perfectly with the Train data. I can get fitted, model summary etc by using different broom functionalities like glance or augment. And each group has a model of its own the way I wnated.

The challenge is when I want to use this model on the test data.

Seems straight forward but somehow the solution eludes me :(

Comment: I suppose what you mean by "use this model on the test data" is you wanted to make predictions using the test data. You can try `predict(fit, new_data = test_df)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you fit to nested data like that, you end up with many models, not just one, so you will need to also to set yourself up to predict on *many models*.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

data(Orange)

Orange <- as_tibble(Orange)

orange_fit <- Orange %>% 
  nest(data = c(-Tree)) %>%    ## this sets up five separate models
  mutate(
    fit = map(data, ~ lm(age ~ circumference, data = .x))
  ) 

## the "test data" here is `circumference = c(50, 100, 150)`
orange_fit %>%
  select(Tree, fit) %>%
  crossing(circumference = c(50, 100, 150)) %>%
  mutate(new_data = map(circumference, ~tibble(circumference = .)),
         predicted_age = map2_dbl(fit, new_data, predict))
#> # A tibble: 15 x 5
#>    Tree  fit    circumference new_data         predicted_age
#>    <ord> <list>         <dbl> <list>                   <dbl>
#>  1 3     <lm>              50 <tibble [1 × 1]>          392.
#>  2 3     <lm>             100 <tibble [1 × 1]>          994.
#>  3 3     <lm>             150 <tibble [1 × 1]>         1596.
#>  4 1     <lm>              50 <tibble [1 × 1]>          331.
#>  5 1     <lm>             100 <tibble [1 × 1]>          927.
#>  6 1     <lm>             150 <tibble [1 × 1]>         1523.
#>  7 5     <lm>              50 <tibble [1 × 1]>          385.
#>  8 5     <lm>             100 <tibble [1 × 1]>          824.
#>  9 5     <lm>             150 <tibble [1 × 1]>         1264.
#> 10 2     <lm>              50 <tibble [1 × 1]>          257.
#> 11 2     <lm>             100 <tibble [1 × 1]>          647.
#> 12 2     <lm>             150 <tibble [1 × 1]>         1037.
#> 13 4     <lm>              50 <tibble [1 × 1]>          282.
#> 14 4     <lm>             100 <tibble [1 × 1]>          640.
#> 15 4     <lm>             150 <tibble [1 × 1]>          999.
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Notice at the end we have a prediction for *each* point in the test set (3) for *each* model (5).

Comment: Thank you for the solution :) .. and sorry for the long delay to revert..